# get the most common source-destination trajectories in R

Tags: r, r-sp, r-grid, od

I have two spatial points dataset, one for origins and one for destinations.

I'd like to take the most recurring trajectories from these coordinates.

```
> salidas
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 4385 
extent      : -8.694846, -8.339238, 41.00827, 41.25749  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3
names       :               cod, duracion, franja_h 
min values  : 1.37263685362e+18,      315,        1 
max values  : 1.37274729362e+18,    13830,       96 

> llegadas
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 4385 
extent      : -8.756604, -7.739523, 40.48858, 41.4262  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3
names       :               cod, duracion, franja_h 
min values  : 1.37263685362e+18,      315,        1 
max values  : 1.37274729362e+18,    13830,       96
```

I think the points should be kept discreet, as they are not too specific and do not give too much information, so I've made a grid of X and Y coordinates for it.

```
> GridSalidas
          X       Y Count
1   -8.3375 41.1975     1
2   -8.5125 41.2025     1
3   -8.5325 41.1425     1
4   -8.5325 41.2075     1
5   -8.5325 41.2225     1
6   -8.5475 41.2025     1
7   -8.5475 41.2075     1
8   -8.5475 41.2325     1
9   -8.5525 41.2075     1
10  -8.5525 41.2175     1

> GridLlegadas
          X       Y Count
1   -7.7375 41.2975     1
2   -7.8625 40.4875     1
3   -8.1475 41.1875     1
4   -8.3075 41.1975     1
5   -8.4725 41.3225     1
6   -8.4875 41.1875     1
7   -8.4925 41.1925     1
8   -8.4975 41.1875     2
9   -8.5025 41.0425     1
10  -8.5025 41.1925     1
```

As a result, I'd like to find out which trajectories are more common depending on the origin and the destination.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say _recurring trajectory_? Do they need to have the exact same origin and destination? Or just the relative positions? Besides, got some example data frames?

Comment: By frequent trajectory I mean the trajectories that are most repeated in the data frame, so that only the most common ones can be visualized. does not have to have the exact origin or destination, as it is too concrete, but what I want to achieve is to see which ones are the most repeated, that's why I use a grid, as a point is too concrete.

Comment: I mean, for examples, is
`Original = (-7.5, 40), destination = (-8.5, 42)` the same trajectory as `Original = (-6.5, 39), destination = (-7.5, 41)`? Since both have the same x and y displacements.

Comment: No, for example: {origin = (5.45, 6.25), destination = (6.35, 6.75)} and other trajectory for example  {origin = (5.50, 6.25), destination = (6.35, 6.80)} are more or less the same.because they have left a point O and go to a point D that is more or less the same, the dataset has more than 5000 items, so there are many routes that are repeated as a point of origin and destination, but for different moments of time. What I want is to get out which of these routes are the most repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are asking for is some multi-dimensional binning.

I generated a random dataset `dt` of origin and destination for the purpose of demonstration. The output result is a `data.table` that gives the following information about the most frequent trajectory:

- Lower and upper limits of the x-y coordinates that define the *source* grid
- Lower and upper limits of the x-y coordinates that define the *destination* grid
- Count

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

N <- 5000
set.seed(123)
gp <- 0.1 #grid precision

# Generate an example dataset -----
{
  dt <- data.table(
    origin_x = rnorm(N, 1, 0.1),
    origin_y = rnorm(N, 2, 0.1),
    destination_x = rnorm(N, 11, 0.1),
    destination_y = rnorm(N, 12, 0.1)
  )
}

# Grid formation ----
{
  ## Defining the ranges (LL and UL stand for lower and upper limits, respectively) ----
  {
    origin_x_LL <- dt[, origin_x] %>% min %>% divide_by(gp) %>% floor %>% multiply_by(gp)
    origin_x_UL <- dt[, origin_x] %>% max %>% divide_by(gp) %>% ceiling %>% multiply_by(gp)
    origin_y_LL <- dt[, origin_y] %>% min %>% divide_by(gp) %>% floor %>% multiply_by(gp)
    origin_y_UL <- dt[, origin_y] %>% max %>% divide_by(gp) %>% ceiling %>% multiply_by(gp)
    destination_x_LL <- dt[, destination_x] %>% min %>% divide_by(gp) %>% floor %>% multiply_by(gp)
    destination_x_UL <- dt[, destination_x] %>% max %>% divide_by(gp) %>% ceiling %>% multiply_by(gp)
    destination_y_LL <- dt[, destination_y] %>% min %>% divide_by(gp) %>% floor %>% multiply_by(gp)
    destination_y_UL <- dt[, destination_y] %>% max %>% divide_by(gp) %>% ceiling %>% multiply_by(gp)
  }
  ## Forming the breaks for binning ----
  {
    origin_x_brks <- seq(origin_x_LL, origin_x_UL, by = gp)
    origin_y_brks <- seq(origin_y_LL, origin_y_UL, by = gp)
    destination_x_brks <- seq(destination_x_LL, destination_x_UL, by = gp)
    destination_y_brks <- seq(destination_y_LL, destination_y_UL, by = gp)
  }
  ## Computing the number of bins ----
  {
    origin_x_Nbin <- length(origin_x_brks) - 1L
    origin_y_Nbin <- length(origin_y_brks) - 1L
    destination_x_Nbin <- length(destination_x_brks) - 1L
    destination_y_Nbin <- length(destination_y_brks) - 1L
  }
  ## Binning ----
  {
    origin_x_bin <- .bincode(dt[, origin_x], origin_x_brks, include.lowest = T)
    origin_y_bin <- .bincode(dt[, origin_y], origin_y_brks, include.lowest = T)
    destination_x_bin <- .bincode(dt[, destination_x], destination_x_brks, include.lowest = T)
    destination_y_bin <- .bincode(dt[, destination_y], destination_y_brks, include.lowest = T)
  }
}

# Counting grid frequency ----
{
  grid_count <-
    lapply(seq(origin_x_Nbin), function(i) {
      lapply(seq(origin_y_Nbin), function(j) {
        lapply(seq(destination_x_Nbin), function(m) {
          lapply(seq(destination_y_Nbin), function(n) {
            this_count = which(origin_x_bin == i & origin_y_bin == j & destination_x_bin == m & destination_y_bin == n) %>% length
            return(data.table(origin_x_LL = origin_x_brks[i], origin_x_UL = origin_x_brks[i + 1],
                              origin_y_LL = origin_y_brks[j], origin_y_UL = origin_y_brks[j + 1],
                              destination_x_LL = destination_x_brks[m], destination_x_UL = destination_x_brks[m + 1],
                              destination_y_LL = destination_y_brks[n], destination_y_UL = destination_y_brks[n + 1],
                              count = this_count))
          }) %>% rbindlist
        }) %>% rbindlist
      }) %>% rbindlist
    }) %>% rbindlist
}

# Getting the most frequent grid ----
{
  print(grid_count[count == max(count)])
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just what I was looking for!!